# discord.py Why @client.command dont work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

Nothing happens when i run the register command. I have already tried everything, but nothing helps(
import discord
import env
from discord.ext import commands

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

TOKEN = env.discord_token("DISCORD_TOKEN")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Im ready to go : {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!instagram"):
        await message.channel.send('https://www.instagram.com')
    if message.content.startswith("!youtube"):
        await message.channel.send("https://www.youtube.com/channel/fsaf!212faf")

#Dont work
@client.command
async def register(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send(arg2, arg1)



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(807733964214321878)
    await member.add_roles(role_1)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: How are you "running" the command? What do you think should happen when you do so?

Comment: I write to the bot in private messages "!reg" and the argument, it's supposed to return that argument to me, but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not

```
@client.command
```

The correct way to use it is..

```
@client.command(name="Command name", description="Command Description")
```

The 'name' and 'description' arguments are optional..

Another thing...
Since you use the 'on_message' event..
Do this...

```
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
    return
    if message.content.startswith("!instagram"):
        await message.channel.send('https://www.instagram.com')
    if message.content.startswith("!youtube"):
        await message.channel.send("https://www.youtube.com/channel/fsaf!212faf")

    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Your whole code according to me:

```
import discord 
import env 
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

TOKEN = env.discord_token("DISCORD_TOKEN")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Im ready to go : {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
       return
    if message.content.startswith("!instagram"):
        await message.channel.send('https://www.instagram.com')
    elif message.content.startswith("!youtube"):
        await message.channel.send("https://www.youtube.com/channel/fsaf!212faf")
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command(name='reg')
async def register(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send(arg2, arg1)



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(807733964214321878)
    await member.add_roles(role_1)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Check the answer again...I have edited it

Comment: As far as I understand it correctly, this need to add it to the end of def on message, then it outputs the following: Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "reg" is not found

Comment: Have you given your command name?? I have simplified the answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this: bot. add_command(reg), but nothing changes. Can you please fix my code with your own developments? it seems to me that I am too stupid in this topic

Comment: In your Discord Text Channel...type "!reg arg1 arg2"

Comment: Thank you very much! After I changed the line: @client. command(name= 'reg'), everything worked. Sorry for my stupidity)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I know the answer. You are using:

```
@Client.command
```

#### Here is the error:

You are supposed to use parenthesis after `command`, i.e.,
you should use:

```
@Client.command()
```

I think this would work. If this doesn't work tell me so that I would check it again.

Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help(

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is incorrect - yes the reasoning is correct BUT remember: Python is CAPS SENSITIVE.

The error you have made is very simple I couldn't even notice it.

What you have to do is:

```py
@client.command()
```

Now, you may say there is no difference between the answer above and the answer I have written here, BUT if you watch carefully, in the answer above me there was a Capital letter C.

Be. Careful. On. Capital. Letters.

Also, name and description are optional inside of the parenthesis.

If you need more help please DM me (officer grr#6609)

Comment: What with a capital letter, what with a small one. It doesn't work without a name

Comment: @client.command must be LOWER case at all times